# How to do a search using sqlalchemy from chinese character Column?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

code

```
result=Minicomputer.query.filter_by(u'名称'='CC670a').first()
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
  File "/mnt/hgfs/python/flask/Project/__init__.py", line 34, in create_app
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
  File "/mnt/hgfs/python/flask/Project/main/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views, errors
  File "/mnt/hgfs/python/flask/Project/main/views.py", line 95
    result=Minicomputer.query.filter_by(u'名称'='CC670a').first()
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

**minicomputer** is a table using chinese character Column name

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:1qaz2wsx@localhost/chhai?charset=utf8', convert_unicode=True, echo=False)
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.reflect(engine)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

class Storage(Base):

__table__ = Base.metadata.tables['storage']

def __repr__(self):
    return '<Storage %r>' % self.Storage_Name
class Minicomputer(Base):

__table__ = Base.metadata.tables['minicomputer']

def __repr__(self):
    name = u'名称'
    return '<Minicomputer %r>' % self.ID
```

Comment: u'名称'='CC670a' is an expression. You are telling it that u'名称' is equal to the string "CC670a" I'm not a SQLAlchemy user so won't put an answer together, but I suspect you are only supposed to have a single value in the parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do a column mapping solved this error

```
class Minicomputer(Base):
    __table__ = Base.metadata.tables['minicomputer']
    name = __table__.c[u'名称']


    def __repr__(self):

        return '<Minicomputer %r>' % self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter_by` is a function taking in keyword arguments. `filter` is a function that takes in an expression. So, either

```
Minicomputer.query.filter_by(名称='CC670a')
```

or

```
Minicomputer.query.filter(Minicomputer.名称 == 'CC670a')
```

You'll need to be on Python 3 for this to work, by the way, since Python 2 does not allow non-ASCII identifiers.

Comment: Python2.7 here,so there is other way to solve this error ?Minicomputer.query.filter_by(名称='CC670a') shows SyntaxError: invalid syntax